# is there is way to make text fill the button size using css or html only?

Tags: html, css

i am trying to make responsive button with text on it but i couldn't make the text stay in the button size using css and html only

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.button {
  float: left;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6vmin;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='chatstyle.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="button">justlongtext</button>
</body>
```

using this code and then try to resize the window for example to 190px 310px 
the text will go out of the button

Comment: You mean to make the text smaller as the button go smaller right?

Comment: @ToanLu yes right smaller or bigger in the width and height size of the button

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `width` and `height` of button so when the text is larger than button, it will overflow. You can fix it by setting only one dimension (only `width` or only `height`). Instead of second dimension you add some padding to make button look nice:

```css
.only-height {
    height: 50px;
}

.only-width {
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button class="only-height">This is very long text, but it won't overflow because only the height is set.</button>
<br>
<button class="only-width">This is very long text, but it won't overflow because only the width is set.</button>
```

If you want to resize the text by the size of the button I would recommended you to use javascript. But you can also do it without javascript. You can also use `vw` and `vh` in font size, but you have to set it manually depend on the text length. [Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/mozkomor05/Loz8ea0q/). It works great but if the text is too long it will overflow so you will have to change `calc(0.9vw + 0.9vh)` to smaller value like `calc(0.5vw + 0.5vh)`. [Second example](https://jsfiddle.net/mozkomor05/as79qhz1/).

Comment: thank you lot this helped me understand the reason of the overflow happening